# Unable to remove escape charactors from the print

Tags: python, escaping, beautifulsoup, html-escape-characters

Hi I am trying to extract information to put into a list containing plain text but can't find a way to remove the escape characters.

I am very new to python and programming in general. I have been trying to solve this but unable to find one.

This is my code:

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


x=1
while x<2:

    url = "http://search.insing.com/ts/food-drink/bars-pubs/bars-pubs?page=" +str(x)
    htmlfile = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile.decode('utf-8','ignore'))
    reshtml = soup.find("div", "results").find_all("h3")
    reslist = []
    for item in reshtml:
            res = item.get_text()
            reslist.append(res)

    print reslist
    x += 1
```

Comment: What is your expected output vs. your actual output? Also, I don't understand this `x=1; while x<2: ... x += 1` construction...

Answer (score 1):

seems like you're really after the text in the anchor there, consider changing

```
reshtml = soup.find("div", "results").find_all("h3")
```

to:

```
reshtml = [h3.a for h3 in soup.find("div", "results").find_all("h3")]
```

also change:

```
reslist.append(res)
```

to:

```
reslist.append(' '.join(res.split()))
```

here is what I get after changing:

```
[u'Parco Caffe', u'AdstraGold Microbrewery & Bistro Bar', 
 u'Alkaff Mansion Ristorante', u'The Fat Cat Bistro', u'Gravity Bar', 
 u'The Wine Company (Evans Road)', u'Serenity Spanish Bar & Restaurant (VivoCity)', 
 u'The New Harbour Cafe & Bar', u'Indian Times', u'Sunset Bay Beach Bar',  
 u'Friends @ Jelita', u'Talk Cock Sing Song @ Thomson',  
 u'En Japanese Dining Bar (UE Square)', u'Magma German Wine Bistro',  
 u"Tam Kah Shark's Fin", u'Senso Ristorante & Bar',  
 u'Hard Rock Cafe (HPL House)', u'St. James Power Station',  
 u'The St. James', u'Brotzeit German Bier Bar & Restaurant (Vivocity)']
```

Answer (score 0):

The current output looks like this:

```
[u'\n\r\n                Parco Caffe\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                AdstraGold Microbrewery & Bistro Bar\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Alkaff Mansion Ristorante\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                The Fat Cat Bistro\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Gravity Bar\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                The Wine Company\r\n                    (Evans Road)\r\n                \n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Serenity Spanish Bar & Restaurant\r\n                    (VivoCity)\r\n                \n', 
 u'\n\r\n                The New Harbour Cafe & Bar\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Indian Times\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Sunset Bay Beach Bar\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Friends @ Jelita\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Talk Cock Sing Song @ Thomson\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                En Japanese Dining Bar\r\n                    (UE Square)\r\n                \n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Magma German Wine Bistro\n', 
 u"\n\r\n                Tam Kah Shark's Fin\n", 
 u'\n\r\n                Senso Ristorante & Bar\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Hard Rock Cafe\r\n                    (HPL House)\r\n                \n', 
 u'\n\r\n                St. James Power Station \n', 
 u'\n\r\n                The St. James\n', 
 u'\n\r\n                Brotzeit German Bier Bar & Restaurant\r\n                    (Vivocity)\r\n                \n']
```

Adding these lines before the print:

```
reslist = [y.replace('\n','').replace('\r','') for y in reslist]
reslist = [y.strip() for y in reslist]
```

Gives me this output:

```
[u'Alkaff Mansion Ristorante', 
 u'Parco Caffe', 
 u'AdstraGold Microbrewery & Bistro Bar', 
 u'Gravity Bar', 
 u'The Fat Cat Bistro', 
 u'The Wine Company                    (Evans Road)', 
 u'Serenity Spanish Bar & Restaurant                    (VivoCity)', 
 u'The New Harbour Cafe & Bar', 
 u'Indian Times', 
 u'Sunset Bay Beach Bar', 
 u'Friends @ Jelita', 
 u'Talk Cock Sing Song @ Thomson', 
 u'En Japanese Dining Bar                    (UE Square)', 
 u'Magma German Wine Bistro', 
 u"Tam Kah Shark's Fin", 
 u'Senso Ristorante & Bar', 
 u'Hard Rock Cafe                    (HPL House)', 
 u'St. James Power Station', 
 u'The St. James', 
 u'Brotzeit German Bier Bar & Restaurant                    (Vivocity)']
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Guy's answer is much better, and more BeautifulSoup specific.